# How to get the slick carrousel inside a tabel column in a existing view?

Tags: views

I generated a table with the help of views e.g.

```
Name | Title
```

I would like to extend the table with a third column e.g. Photo

```
Name | Title | Photo
```

The foto should be in the slick slider gallery. So if there are more then 2 pictures there should be an arrow left/right

Can this be done with: module Views Field View?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can add the photo field in views and also one Global PHP field below that where you can write the code for slick carousal.

Comment: Hi Tejas, sounds good but I have no idea how to do that... can you give me some more details?